# Adding a float attribute to an entity in coreData and increment it on every addition of new Object

Tags: ios, ios5, core-data

I am new to coreData,I am working on a sample application where I have added a float type attribute called displayOrder to an entity called "Test". I want to increment this display order on adding each test Object. For this to happen, I have written the below code , but it is not working, I want to know where I am going wrong

```
- (void)insertNewObject:(NSString *)fileName
{    
    Test *testName = [NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"Test" inManagedObjectContext:self.managedObjectContext];

    [testName setName:fileName];

    NSManagedObject *lastObject = [self.controller.fetchedObjects lastObject];
    float lastObjectDisplayOrder = [[lastObject valueForKey:@"displayOrder"] floatValue];
    NSLog(@"%f",lastObjectDisplayOrder);
    [testName setValue:[NSNumber numberWithDouble:lastObjectDisplayOrder + 1.0] forKey:@"displayOrder"];

    // Save the context.
    NSError *error = nil;
    if (![self.managedObjectContext save:&error]) {
        // Replace this implementation with code to handle the error appropriately.
        // abort() causes the application to generate a crash log and terminate. You should not use this function in a shipping application, although it may be useful during development. 
        NSLog(@"Unresolved error %@, %@", error, [error userInfo]);
        abort();
    }
}
```

Actually, the problem is it increments for the first time i.e from 0 to 1 but after this I get always 1.

Regards
Ranjit

Comment: What about `NSLog(@"%f",lastObjectDisplayOrder);`? Is it printing `0` always?

Comment: Hi @Aadhira, first time it is 0 second time it is 1 and later it is 1 always

Comment: Can you show the sort descriptor on your fetched results controller? It seems that the `fetchedObjects lastObject` is always returning the object with a value of 1 for `lastObjectDisplayOrder'

Comment: Hi @ChrisH, I figured it out, Now suppose, instead of getting lastObject if I want objectAtIndex:0, I get the error stating, arrayOutofbound index

Comment: If you're asking for an object at index 0 of an array, and getting an out of bounds error, that means your array is empty. Either way, I'd say your problem is that you are incrementing the `lastObjectDisplayOrder` based on the value of the wrong object in your array. If the number is the same as the array count why not just use that as the value you increment?

Answer (score 0):

Your problem may be related to the part where you load the lastObject and you may not update the fetchedresultscontroller, I would suggest creating an iVar and assign the value on the init or viewDidLoad then use that iVar to update and get the correct value, also, if you are not using decimals for this and you only need the order maybe an Integer should be better.

Comment: When I insert new Object, I unhide a new ViewController where I add the name of the object then I hide the ViewController. So I add the iVar and get the lastObject in ViewDidLoad, then it cant be possible because it is not called , because I am only hiding the ViewController

Answer (score 0):

You could use Core Data Aggregate Functions to get the maximum displayOrder value.

Something like:

```
- (NSNumber *)nextDisplayOrder {
    NSManagedObjectContext *context = self.managedObjectContext;

    NSEntityDescription *entityDescription = [NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"Test" inManagedObjectContext:context];
    NSFetchRequest *request = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];
    [request setEntity:entityDescription];
    [request setResultType:NSDictionaryResultType];

    NSExpression *keyExpression = [NSExpression expressionForKeyPath:@"displayOrder"];
    NSExpression *maxExpression = [NSExpression expressionForFunction:@"max:" arguments:[NSArray arrayWithObject:keyExpression]];

    NSExpressionDescription *description = [[NSExpressionDescription alloc] init];
    [description setName:@"maxDisplayOrder"];
    [description setExpression:maxExpression];
    [description setExpressionResultType:NSFloatAttributeType];

    [request setPropertiesToFetch:[NSArray arrayWithObject:description]];

    NSError *error = nil;
    NSArray *results = [context executeFetchRequest:request error:&error];
    if (results.count == 1) {
        NSNumber *maxDisplayOrder = [[results objectAtIndex:0] valueForKey:@"displayOrder"];
        return [NSNumber numberWithFloat:[maxDisplayOrder floatValue] + 1.f];
    } else {
        NSLog(@"Could not get next displayOrder. Error: %@", error);
    }

    return nil;
}
```

Some additional notes:

- use an integer rather than a float for discrete values like the displayOrder
- this boilerplate code can be written in 2 lines with [MagicalRecord](https://github.com/magicalpanda/MagicalRecord), so you might want to check that out
- [more info on aggregate functions](http://brianflove.com/2012/09/26/core-data-aggregate-functions/)

Comment: Not sure. There are a lot of unknowns here, while the code I posted should work in any case, as long as you save the MOC after each insertion, which you do. Are you reloading self.controller before every insert call? Are you sorting the objects by displayOrder (appropriate sort descriptor for the fetch request)? NSLog self.controller.fetchedObjects and see how your objects look like. You are also mixing NSNumber double and float methods, although that's likely not the issue here. You should really be using integers for this property, I suggest you change the model.

Comment: Yes, I am sorting the objects by displayOrder.how to use your function , is this the right way to pass the value to the attribute [test setdisplayOrder:[self nextDisplayOrder];

Comment: I am trying to call the function and get the value returned by your function, but the function crashes at line NSArray *results = ...

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to set the result type to NSDictionaryResultType. This should be fine now.

Comment: My code is also working, the problem was I was sorting in descending Order. So their is no need to use Magical record

Comment: I'm glad that you figured it out. I never said you have to use magical record. That is just a convenience library so you don't have to type a lot of code. As I pointed out in the previous comment, the code I posted should work in any case, while your code only works if the NSFetchedResultsController is properly configured (which it obviously wasn't).

Comment: Hi @Matej Bukovinski, I have a doubt here, I want to sort the objects in descending order, So now I should take displayOrder from firstObject. How to do that